# Forward everything from misspelled domain (DNS)

Tags: dns, forwarding

I have two domains:

1. example.com
2. exampel.com (wrongly spelled version of 1)

Now, I want to 'forward' everything from domain 2 to domain 1, so for example:

- www.exampel.com --> www.example.com (for every subdomain)
- info@exampel.com --> info@example.com (for all email addresses).

I understand that I can configure it all manually (per subdomain, per email address), but is there not a way to basically map domain 2 to domain 1 completely?

Thanks!

Comment: @Logman Literally the first sentence in the post is "I have two domains"

Comment: lol sorry :)  watching movie and board not good

Comment: Just to clarify you are talking about confiuring a DNS's ZONE configuration. Not forwarding on a client computer or a non authoritative DNS server, correct?

Comment: What are you using for your DNS server for your domains?  If you were running your own DNS servers and using bind, then it would certainly be possible to create a single zone file such that all the records are relative.  Then simply setup the server to use the same file for both domains.

Comment: I use a hosted solution for DNS (transip). I would switch if there is a better alternative though. I'm indeed talking about a DNS zone config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DNAME record to do this, which on a modern version of DNS software that supports EDNS0 (e.g., BIND9) will do what you want and behave much better than a wildcard CNAME, but still synthesize appropriate CNAMEs on the fly for backwards compatibility with non-EDNS0-aware DNS servers.  See [RFC 6672](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6672.txt) and [RFC 2672](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2672.txt).